# Не могу создать библиотеку на c# (не найти rebuild solution) в visual studio code

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-code

Всем привет! Я создал свою первую библиотеку на C#. Но не понимаю где в visual studio code мне найти rebuild solution. Не знаю имеет это значение или нет но стоит linux mint и именно поэтому стоит visual studio code. На всякий случай кину скрин экрана.

Comment: visual studio code != visual studio, вы можете билдить через консоль или создать build task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно воспользоваться командой .NET Core для сборки: `dotnet build` (при этом в текущей рабочей директории должен находиться **файл проекта**, иначе его нужно будет указать после ключа `--project`).

По умолчанию, компилятор C# использует инкрементальную компиляцию, так что того что в интерфейсе Microsoft Visual Studio называлось `rebuild` - не произойдёт при выполнении стандартной команды сборки.
Для принудительной чистой сборки проекта *с нуля* нужно использовать флаг `--no-incremental`, то есть писать: `dotnet build --no-incremental`.

Команда **dotnet build** хорошо описана в [официальной документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build).

Так же отмечу, что "решение" - это понятие более свойственное большой Microsoft Visual Studio, и (на сколько я понимаю) используется ей для агрегации проектов и конфигураций. Сам же .NET использует понятие "проект" - именно **проект** компилируется в отдельную .NET-сборку. Хотя в .NET Core есть возможность работать с решениями (`dotnet new sln` и `dotnet sln …`), я не встречал им применения кроме как для запуска unit-тестов командой `dotnet test`.
Проект .NET Core определяется файлом проекта: для C# они имеют расширение `.csproj`, для F# - `.fsproj`. Есть и другие.

Comment: большое спасибо за такой развернутый ответ! Сегодня буду пробовать! Отпишу сюда

Comment: Спасибо все получилось

Comment: Если ответ помог - не забывайте помечать его соответствующим образом.